# Linq To XML Vs Open XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to modify the content of a word 2013 document programmatically and I know this can be done for the best by manipulating its XML.
As far as I know, there are two technologies for such a task and they are Linq To XML and Open XML.

Since I'm not an expert on the subject anyway, I'd like to know something more about the differences between the two and what would be the easier to use.

In order to use Open XML, one needs to install the SDK, isn't it? 
Whilst for using Linq to XML, just the .NET framework it's enough.

Is that correct? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'd look into the OpenXML SDK.  Though you can do this with LINQ to XML, you'll have to read a lot of documentation and you *will* shoot yourself in the foot.

The OpenXML SDK makes this is a bit easier, as it will handle a lot of things for you - particularly the relationships between all the various XML documents.

[Eric White's blog](http://www.ericwhite.com/) is a good source of information.

Comment: So you suggest Open XML would be easier.                                                 I would have said the contrary! Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

For reading and modifying Word document you can use Word Interop in C#.

Add reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word and try this-

```
var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at it once and I gathered it is useful for Office documents. It reminds about the constructs you have in VBA, like Range etc, which I used. Anyway, I had some difficulties to move inside a text file to the points where you need to write something. For this, I think an XML could help you. Do you agree?

Comment: If your text file is simple you can just use StreamWriter to Read and Write at any specific position. I am not sure if you are trying to modify an XML file, are you? For that you can use System.Xml in C# which gives you full control to Read/Write an XML file.

Comment: Thanks. I have some docx and xls files to write to at specific positions. The content to write, I've just read it from other txt files. To do that I've been thinking to use XML, the reason being I'm not confident with it and this is chace to learn. Having a docx file, you can save it as zip and then you'll have an XML, so modify it and you'll have your docx modified. Is that correct?